# JQuery next class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to grab the first class, after a given class?

The code below only selects the first class (I'm aware of what `first` does) but I want it to select each first `.FAQAnswers` after each `FAQName` is this possible?

```
 $(".FAQName").click(function () {
    $('.FAQAnswers').first().toggle(200);
 });


<div class="FAQName">Question</div>
...
<div class="FAQAnswers">Answer</div>

<div class="FAQName">Question</div>
...
<div class="FAQAnswers">Answer</div>
```

Comment: Nitpick: You should be using a [definition list `<dl>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/dl)

Comment: To be fair, I have some HTML between the two divs, they aren't paired directly next to one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the needed element with [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
$(".FAQName").click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".FAQAnswers").next().toggle(200);
});
```

Comment: isnt toggle being deprecated

Comment: @user1743214 It was `toggle` event.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I also discovered `prevUntil()`!